# How to trace an SSIS package using Extended Events?

Tags: sql-server-2012, trace

I'm trying to figure out how to trace only SSIS packages accessing a database. I think one way (albeit probably not perfect) to find these queries using SQL are using sys.dm_exec_sessions and checking client_interface_name for the value "OLE DB" (at least for this database). However, I can't find the correct predicate for this in EE. Is there another way?

SQL Server 2012 SP2

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by tracing queries from SSIS ?

Comment: Is SSIS really the only thing that could connect to this database using OLEDB? Doesn't SSIS also populate application name which - while spoofable - should be an easier filter in this case?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that would be the only thing for this database. From a SQL Task, the application name (client_app_name) is Microsoft SQL Server.